# The condition where the system below just begins to oscillate when disturbed?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

**We have a system represented by this differential equation:**

$$\frac{d^2y(t)}{dt^2} + b\frac{dy(t)}{dt} + cy(t) = u(t)$$

Our objective is to determine the condition where this system just begins to oscillate when disturbed.

**Here is how I have interpreted this question:**

My first move is to take the Laplace Transform of the differential equation.

$$\mathscr{L}\lbrace\frac{d^2y(t)}{dt^2}\rbrace + \mathscr{L}\lbrace b\frac{dy(t)}{dt}\rbrace + \mathscr{L}\lbrace cy(t)\rbrace = \mathscr{L}\lbrace u(t)\rbrace$$

$$S^2Y(S) + bSY(S) + cY(S) = U(S)$$

$$Y(S)[S^2 + bS + c] = U(S)$$

and so, the transfer function $H(S) = \frac{1}{S^2 + bS + c}$.

Do I need to take the Laplace here?

Since we are looking to derive the condition where a disturbance leads to oscillation, we can model this situation as an Harmonic Oscillator of the form:

$$\frac{d^2y(t)}{dt^2} + 2 \zeta \omega_{n}\frac{dy(t)}{dt} + \omega_{n}^{2}y(t) = 0$$

Also, there are 4 flavours of damping:
1. Undamped  ($\zeta = 0$)
2. Underdamped ($0 < \zeta < 1$)
3. Overdamped  ($\zeta > 1$)
4. Critically Damped  ($\zeta = 1$)

The only flavour that exhibits oscillation is the Underdamped case.

So using the condition $0 < \zeta < 1$ and the fact that $b = 2\zeta\omega_{n}$ and $c = \omega_{n}^{2}$

So, $0 < \frac{b}{2\omega_{n}} < 1 \implies 0 < b < 2\omega_{n}$.

$\omega_{n} = \sqrt{c} \implies 0 < b < 2\sqrt{c}$.

Is this the correct way to answer this question?

All feedback is welcome.

Comment: I guess your Laplace transform, if needed or not, is not right overall. The Laplace transform of the second derivative for example is given by $\mathcal{L}\left(\frac{d^2 y(x)}{dx^2}\right)~=~s^2 Y(s) - s y(0) - y'(0)$ and not only by $s^2 Y(s)$. Or are there any initial conditions you did not mentioned?

Comment: Ah yes, there are no initial conditions in this question.

Comment: I just realized, that this does not effect the transfer function $H(s)$ but I guess it is important to do the right transfrom when you want to use it later on. Additionally I cannot spot any obvious mistake in your argumentation about the oscillation.

Comment: Right on. Thanks.